# Spring Tool Suite can't find JDBC Driver class

Tags: java, spring, maven-3

During the project building, i received an error:

> Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

I have jdbc connector attached to my project (mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar) and i specified in 'database.properties.svn-base' that i'm using MySQL. And the service is running. And I placed this 'jar' int webapp/web-inf/lib/ directory.

But i've noticed, that system can't add this class into Maven dependencies.

How could i resolve this problem?

Comment: `database.properties.svn-base`  **svn-base** is this a typo?

Comment: What do you mean by "specified in `database.properties.svn-base`"? Do you mean in `database.properties`?

Comment: **database.properties.svn-base** is a file on a disk, in STS it appears as **database.properties**. They have the same content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your pom, and remove the jar that you have added by hand

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

*Maven controlles the libs in your target web application lib folder, not the other way arround.*